# get the result of a timer in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

so I have a timer from java.util.timer
and inside its run method I create an object from another class and put the result in a static array like below:

```
public class Generator {

public Timer timer;
int seconds = 2;
final int maxCalls = 3;
int currNumCall = 0;
public static boolean running = false;

public Generator() {
    this.timer = new Timer();
    this.timer.schedule(new ReminderTask(), seconds * 1000);
}

class ReminderTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (currNumCall < maxCalls) {
            System.out.println("picking up a new call");
            running = true;
            int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 2);
            Call call;
            if (i > 0) {
                call = new Call("high", LocalDateTime.now());

            } else {
                call = new Call("low", LocalDateTime.now());
            }
            calls.add(call);
            currNumCall += 1;
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new ReminderTask(), seconds * 1000);
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
            running = false;
        }

    }

}
```

and in another class I initiate an object from the generator class in order to fill the calls array
now I need to do some operations on the calls so i do some thing like this below :

```
public class Fire_staton_problem {

public static ArrayList<Junior> juniors = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Senior> seniors = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Director> directors = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Call> calls = new ArrayList<>();
public Generator generator;
public Fire_staton_problem() {
    generator = new Generator();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

Fire_staton_problem f = new Fire_staton_problem();
    while(f.generator.isRunning()) {
        if (calls.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(calls);
        }else {
            System.out.println("empty :)");
        }
    }

}

}
```

unfortunately that does not work ... what could I do to be able handle the result of the timer continuously I mean keep checking if the data exist then do stuff, I do not want to just iterate on the array...thanks in advance and please inform if the question not so clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Producer-Consumer pattern, because this is essentially what it is - `Generator` is the producer, and your `Fire_staton_problem` is the consumer. Obvious things:

1. Your `while` loop busy spins checking the list, but what you need here is a `BlockingQueue` instead of a simple list, so when it is empty it will pause the `main` thread, and will wake it up when your `Generator` puts a `Call` into it.
2. You don't need to create a new instance of `Timer` to run the task once again, just use `Timer(task, 0, delay)` constructor to [repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-) the task.